# getting an error on trying to launch Chrome using Protractor

Tags: protractor, webdriver

I'm trying to launch the browser through Protractor. I downloaded webdriver through terminal by giving `webdriver-manager update` command. This is downloading the latest chromedriver v74, but the chrome browser is v73.

How to explicitly set the WebDriver version?

I'm getting the following error:

```
[11:09:13] E/driverProvider - Error code: 135
[11:09:13] E/driverProvider - Error message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
[11:09:13] E/driverProvider - Error: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.2 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.70 seconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'Acsahs-MBP', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:45:3f89:2e8b:ab96%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.2', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Local.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:69:23)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:5:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
[11:09:13] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
```

My config file:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumaddress:'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs:['spec.js']
};
```

Answer (score 1):

is it solved yet? if not then try this.

for my small `selenium-webdriver` test i did these steps after i researched online and here:

1. `npm install selenium-webdriver`
2. `npm install chromedriver`
3. `npm install geckodriver` and opened file library.js and `npm init` and ran `node library.js` **(source code below)**
4. `Error:` `(node:14212) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id` Some long error related to not same chromedriver version. so i checked the chrome browser version manually in the browser. it was `version 73` and my mistake i had downloaded `chromedriver version 74.0`.
5. so go to `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=73.0.3683.68/` download according to your OS and download it in `~/Downloads` .
6. then in open `terminal` in the `~/Downloads` folder.
7. then `USER@DESKTOP:~/Downloads$ unzip ~/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/Downloads` You will get the raw `chromedriver` file in `~/Downloads` folder.
8. now i moved the `ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68` file to two places - `usr/local/bin` and `usr/bin` in my system.
9. there was already a `chromedriver` file in `usr/local/bin` .
10. to move the file - `USER@DESKTOP:~/Downloads$ sudo mv -f ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver` and `USER@DESKTOP:~/Downloads$ sudo mv -f ~/Downloads/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver` you are saying you want to move the file chromedriver from first location to other means replacing any files already in those locations with same name.
11. Last all i did was. close the vscode and relaunched it. and ran my code `node library.js` . and it worked it the chrome browser for me. 
    TOOK AN HOUR FOR ME TO GO THROUGH  AROUND 35-40  STACK-OVERFLOW AND RANDOM ONLINE RESOURCES/QUESTION-ANSWERS BUT WAS WORTH IT. :)

SOURCE CODE : LIBRARY.JS

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var By = webdriver.By;

var until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

driver.get('https://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this as a script to your package.json file

`"scripts": {
    "protactorInstall": "cd ./node_modules/protractor && npm i webdriver-manager@latest"}`

use

`npm run protactorInstall`

to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command from terminal to install particular version

`webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.46`

Hope it helps you

Comment: Hey it helped. It opened the browser but in terminal now I am getting "No specs found."

Comment: No specs found
Finished in 0.001 seconds
Incomplete: No specs found
[11:40:40] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:40:40] I/launcher - Running 0 instances of WebDriver
[11:40:40] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

Comment: Specs :describe ("Enter name feature",function()
{
it('should enter name as Acsah',function()
{
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org/')
});

});

Comment: @Acsahmathew The problem is with spec path. refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/api-overview. Mark the answer as correct if it resolves your question so that will help  those who face the same problem.